# Signup notification in Mailchimp

Tags: wordpress, email, notifications, mailchimp, newsletter

The people who subscribe to mailchimp newsletter through the website newsletter signup form, is it possible to mark those in mailchimp like (web).

Additional info :-
It is a wordpress site.
Looked at all the available mailchimp options. no go.

Answer (score 0):

If premium plugin is an option for you, then get [Chimpy](http://codecanyon.net/item/chimpy-mailchimp-wordpress-plugin/6290216), create a "hidden" interest group named "web" and set the plugin to add all subscribers to that group automatically. You will be able to filter/segment those users easily then.

If you would like to create you own custom implementation, then the best way to this this would be either to have a hidden interest group (as discussed above) or a hidden field that you would not display to users but would send "1" to it from your WordPress site.

You could also create a second MailChimp list but this is not something I would recommend due to many reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try the hidden interest group method.

Comment: Adding a hidden field doesn't change anything. The person's info still appears in the same way on mailchimp without any additional info that would suggest that the signup was through the website.